# what does sed 's#/text##' mean?

Tags: regex, unix, sed, solaris-10

I've just encountered this sed expression and could not figure out exactly what it means. I've performed a google search previously. I'd appreciate any help. What does the initial # and the final ## mean?

```
sed 's#/text##'
```

Comment: The pattern separator - it does not always have to be "/"

Comment: oh ok. so / and # have the same function as delimiter and you can choose either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replace "/text" into null "", try below it gives blank

```
echo /text| sed 's#/text##'
```

Initial # is sed delimited for replace and 
middle # is seperator between first string to be replace, and 
Last # is last delimiter for sed

its same as regex/replace sed command

Comment: Initial # is sed delimited for replace and middle # is seperator between first string (to be replace) and the string to be replace with, and Last # is last delimiter for sed

Comment: It could be written: `sed -e 's/\/text//'` and would mean the same thing.  Using the `#` as a delimiter instead of `/` avoids the use of backslashes, which is usually a good idea.

Comment: oh. ok. thanks. So / and # are the same type of delimiters?

Comment: Roughly, yes.  The first character after the `s` is the delimiter.  Conventionally, that's a slash, but you can use any character as long as you're consistent.  In some contexts, a control character such as control-A can be effective; it doesn't often occur in valid text.